# Get internal file path

Tags: android, file, path, internal

I open an internal file and write to him like this:

```
final String NEWLINE = new String(newLine+"\n");     
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(fileName+".txt",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
osw.write(NEWLINE);
```

I need a way to check if internal file (fileName+".txt") exist.

If not, write newLine to file, else **append** newLine to file.

I tried:

```
File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fileName+".txt");
if(file.exists())...
```

But I don't know the internal file path, and it's not working.

Any suggestions?

More details:

```
private void writeStringToFile(String fileName, String newLine) {
    final String NEWLINE = new String(newLine + "\n");
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
    try { // catches IOException below
        File file = getFileStreamPath(fileName + ".txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            Log.d("DAVID", "File not exist now create him");
            fOut = openFileOutput(fileName + ".txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        } else {
            Log.d("DAVID", "File already exist");
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        }
        // Write the string to the file
        osw.append(NEWLINE);
        // osw.write(NEWLINE);
        // ensure that everything is really written out and close
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the first time it runs it's ok - I'm getting: "File not exist now create him" to Log
In the second time I'm getting FATAL ERROR cause by null pointer.
I think it's because osw  get null fOut

```
osw  = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
```

But how can I prevent it?

Comment: Please try explaining your symptoms, rather than providing meaningless statements like "it's not working". FWIW, `getFileStreamPath()` should work fine, though I would not use `getBaseContext()` -- just call `getFileStreamPath()` on your existing `Context`. Or, use `getFilesDir()` to get at the `File` object for where `openFileOutput()` writes its files.

Comment: you can store filenames that you have used in a [List](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html), then see `if (list.contains(filename))`.

Answer (score 0):

The code above was so wrong I just had to rewrite it :

```
private void apendStringToInternalFile(String fileName, String newLine)
        throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException,
        IOException {
    newLine = new String(newLine + "\n");
    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(fileName + ".txt",
            Context.MODE_APPEND | Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    // MODE_WORLD_READABLE is _deprecated_
    try {
        // ALWAYS SPECIFY ENCODING -
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut, "UTF-8");
        BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        buffer.write(newLine);
        buffer.flush();
    } finally {
        try {
            fOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log this to be on the safe side -
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously the whole issue is not existent. `openFileOutput` will create the file if it doesn't exist and adding the flag `Context.MODE_APPEND` it will append if the file does exist. Copy paste freely